# how to add a 3rd party library to magento?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7, zend-autoloader

The library doesn't need to integrate with magento, it's mostly a wrapper that communicates with an API.

I would like to be able to use this library and make these API calls from within a controller or model.

Where can I put the library? How do I add them to the autoloader?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Look into /lib folder in your website root directory. From [Magento Base Directories](http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories):

> Magento’s library folder is where
>   non-module based Magento code lives.
>   This include a large amount of the
>   system code which allows Magento to
>   run, as well as a number of third
>   party libraries (including the Zend
>   Framework). The library is also the
>   last code pool Magento will search
>   when attempting to autoload a file.

So, in other words, if your library supports zend file naming convention - library classes will be found and loaded by magento autoloader. Otherwise you can get path of your /lib directory with Mage::getBaseDir(‘lib’) and write something like

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/EZComponents/Base/src/base.php');
```

Comment: One of the good approach to autoload library - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085967/how-to-integrate-ezcomponents-with-magento/4636662#4636662

Answer (score 9):

As a solution that works perfectly:
you can extend the varien_event_observer, create your own autoloader function and and by using the controller_front_init_before event you push this autoloader in front of the __autoload stack.
this example of integrating solarium and symphony event dispatcher can explain it :

```
class JeroenVermeulen_Solarium_Model_Observer_Autoloader extends Varien_Event_Observer {

    /**
     * This an observer function for the event 'controller_front_init_before'.
     * It prepends our autoloader, so we can load the extra libraries.
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $event
     */
    public function controllerFrontInitBefore( $event ) {
        spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load'), true, true );
    }

    /**
     * This function can autoloads classes starting with:
     * - Solarium
     * - Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher
     *
     * @param string $class
     */
    public static function load( $class )
    {
        if ( preg_match( '#^(Solarium|Symfony\\\\Component\\\\EventDispatcher)\b#', $class ) ) {
            $phpFile = Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/' . str_replace( '\\', '/', $class ) . '.php';
            require_once( $phpFile );
        }
    }

}
```

and surely your libraries shoud be in the lib pool !
 this solution is provided by @Jeroen Vermeulen, and i thank him :)

Comment: It works perfectly !! Thanks !
Used this for using Bpost library (https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/bpost) with Magento.
Class exemple: https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/bpost/blob/master/Bpost/Order/Box/AtHome.php

Comment: Woot keep the advertising for our extension comming :p

Comment: @JonaPkr can you update your link with the example (https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/bpost/blob/master/src/Bpost/Order/Box/AtHome.php) ? :)

Comment: @RicardoMartins sorry i don't know why but i can't edit my comment :s Guys, my first link is outdated, please follow the good one, tx to Ricardo https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/bpost/blob/master/src/Bpost/Order/Box/AtHome.php